# how to import data from a xml file into datagrid view using linq?

Tags: c#

Im using c# .net , windows form application. I have a XML file which contains two columns and some rows of data. now i have to fill this data into a data grid view. I want to use LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
        // choose you filename there
        XElement xElement = XElement.Load("file.xml");
        // choose appropriate properties
        dataGridView1.DataSource = (from el in xElement.Elements()
                  select new { a = el.Name.ToString(), b = "Whatever"}).ToList();
```